# How to resolve "high disk space utilization by deleted open files" automatically

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage

**Scenario:** Getting high disk space utilization alerts on our machines, possibly because of fast log rotation. And thus openfiles were being created, which we are clearing them manually all the time to free up disk space.

```
lsof /var/log | grep deleted
java       2852 cassandra  532w   REG  253,4 7135800134 1058794 /var/log/cassandra/system.log (deleted)
java       2852 cassandra  534w   REG  253,4 3457184075 1048691 /var/log/cassandra/debug.log (deleted)
java      14252 cassandra  443w   REG  253,4   20971617 3145816 /var/log/spark/master/master.log (deleted)
```

**OS**: CentOS 7

```
uname -a

Linux CAM-EDH-NOD-Q01 3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 7 14:49:57 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**FYI**: Clearing disk space by following https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

Answer (score 1):

For me the files are still open from the processes. And the diskspace is in "use". The only way I know is to restart the processes. After this the files will be released and deleted.

Comment: just use `gzip --keep blabla.log && truncate --size 0 blabla.log`.

Comment: @paladin, if the log writer write based n the position (not append) IMHO this will not help

Comment: So use this `ln -f blabla.log blabla.log.bak && touch blabla.log.new && ln -f blabla.log.new blabla.log && unlink blabla.log.new`

Comment: AFAIK file handle is based on inode number, so this may not work....

Comment: Have you tested it? Because this works.

Comment: Have you tested with jboss?

Comment: No, I've tested it with `nano` and `systemd-journald.service` and those worked fine (and I guess any other logger will work fine too).

Comment: The log files are generated by Cassandra DB, so its not possible to do restart the process that easily. So following https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

FYI: In our logback.xml auto file rotation is in place for every 20MB. But here the open files sizes are in GBs. So can't understand how its causing.

Comment: @Pramod, usually Cassandra is created from multiply hosts. You can use rolling restart.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, we can do rolling restart, but this issue is not resolving as the said scenario is happening again and again after restart also. So, Trying to see if we can know if the same file is being accessed by any other process(may be with file descriptor or so). Any thing in specific that to be checked if we enable audit on that file?

Comment: @Pramod, no. My observation is java use positional write to login files. So you must try some config changes for log rotation. Or decrease the level of logging.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Not sure what you mean by "positional write to login" but our logging level is at "INFO"